# How can I remove a line break and all spaces on the next line in the Sublime Text editor?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, text-editor

It happens many times when we need to remove a line end and unnecessary space between an HTML element. So this could be proven as a time-saving technique.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

1. open Search and replace (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>)
2. enable "Regular Expression" (circled in red)
3. enter `\n\s+` in the search field, clear the replace field
4. press "Replace all"

[image]

This will remove all newlines (`\n+`) followed by all whitespace (`\s+`) in the next line.

Comment: awesome, thanks! just replace with a "space" for a space between words!

Answer (score 8):

In your Sublime Text user settings, you can specify the following to trim trailing white space.

```
"trim_trailing_white_space_on_save": true
```

You might want to have a look at the [Trimmer](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Trimmer) that has a couple of options to trim whitespace.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use \n+ to remove all the unwanted space. If you want to use a single line then  replace with \n online.

Comment: Note that when using `Replace all` it doesn't make any difference if you use `\n+` or `\n`. Also, using this will remove **all** line breaks, reducing the file to a single line.

Answer (score 0):

always trim on saving for sublime 4 (build 4169)

in Preferences.sublime-settings use two params:

```
"trim_trailing_white_space_on_save": "all",
"trim_only_modified_white_space": false,
```